# setting value of an asp.net Label using jquery and Accessing it on Page_Load event in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two pages,  one is item.aspx and one is details.aspx. Now in details.aspx there is an asp.net Label.  I put the name of an item in that label using jquery after the label in the body of the page.

On page load of details.aspx the Label shows the name of the item. It works fine.  But then I have to take the value to the back end c# , which the Label.Text is not able to read.

When **I checked the value using Firebug, the span label value is Empty** but the label shows the name of item in browser. Maybe because page load event is happening first then the jquery code is setting the item name for the Label.
Can we have some work around to fix that so that I can use the Label.Text value on Page_Load event.

Comment: I think you might have to try a new approach. In the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx), anything that jQuery can do to elements on a page happen AFTER the `Page_Load` event in your codebehind.

Comment: You can however use the Label.Text in a subsequent button click.

Comment: please see this question , ive put up again using code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964972/in-asp-net-i-can-not-access-the-label1-text-value-on-page-load-in-c-sharp-when-s

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Code behind page load occurs on server when request is sent to the server.

while jquery document ready occurs on window.onload event which occurs when the complete HTML document is ready in browser for display.

you can use the jquery code to set the label text.

**Update:**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Label1").html("chamara");
            $("#Label2").html($("#Label1").text());
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes i did that and now the text on Label1 is showing just fine but when i try to save that value to a string and use that string value for other things the string dosen't save the value instead it saves the original Text value, altough on page it's rendered fine. Please help, thanks. its really important.

Comment: I tried all other page events like page_PreRender, but they didn;t work, all i have to do now is to get the value from Label1 to a string like this  string name=Label1.Text  but it don't work while Label1's text displays correctly on page. And when i view source, the Label at source displays nothing.(i mean default text). What a bottleneck :9

Comment: you mean once the page is rendered you view the source and the label text is not set? if that's the case how do you set the label text in jquery? See my update

Comment: shows on the front end bit still can;t save the value of label in a string . i mean string name=Label.text  shows no value in string. :(

Comment: when i view source from chrome browser it shows empty but when i debug it with the internal or firebug debugger it shows the value properly. Now i still can't save it to the string value on Page_Load from code behind. i mean string final= Label2.text cannot be saved. please help.

Comment: ive again put up question in more accurate manner here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964972/in-asp-net-i-can-not-access-the-label1-text-value-on-page-load-in-c-sharp-when-s

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ASP hidden field and assign it in query.

```
$hidden = ("#<% hiddenID.ClientID %>")
$hidden.val(" label value here")
```

You can then see the hidden field on the code behind. Sorry for the brief answer, posting from phone.

Comment: Di that and when i view source from chrome browser it shows empty but when i debug it with the internal or firebug debugger it shows the value properly. Now i still can't save it to the string value on Page_Load from code behind. i mean string final= HiddenId.Value; cannot be saved. please help.

Answer (score 0):

As @tymeJV said, Hiddenfield should work.

I'm not sure whether you're setting value of hidden filed in document.ready.

You may want to try below.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnProductName" runat="server" readonly="readonly"/>
```

make it readonly as shown above and assign value client side and it will retain the value and you can have it server side as well.