# Access the Label value on Page load in c# when value set through jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am posting this question again, maybe this time more accurate description.

The problem is , I am using jQuery to set the Label's text value and it works fine on browser, but when I want to save it to string, it does not save it. Here is the 
front End Html Code.

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            var myNewName = "Ronaldo";
           $('#<%= Label1.ClientID %>').text(myNewName);

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Back End C# Code On Page Load

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string mynameCheck = Label1.Text;
        if (mynameCheck=="Ronaldo")
        {
            Response.Write("Yes Name is Fine");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Name's not Fine");

        }
    }
}
```

The result displayed is

```
Name's not Fine
Ronaldo
```

Seems like the string is still Null. Is there any problem of rendering??

Comment: infact if i look at the value of mynameCheck it displays Label. this is quite amazing !!

Comment: If you want to post something back to the server, use an `input` element will be much more suitable. Do note that when you post a form, only value from `input`, `select`, `textarea` and some other user input element within the form will be posted to server.

Comment: ...and use the `val` function to set the "value" attribute.

Comment: Have a look at the generated HTML source instead of the ASP.NET controls. It helps! ;)

Comment: Yes Stefan, the generated code of label1 displays  <span id="Label1">Label</span> . Maybe that's why the i can't put it on a variable. Please tell me what to do !

Comment: asp:Label is server side element, it always renders as a span(HTML element) in a browser, this will not effect any functionality of the original Label

Comment: @Avishek not always ;)

Comment: @Stefan Agreed. But in general cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting value of an asp.net Label using jquery and Accessing it on Page\_Load event in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961848/setting-value-of-an-asp-net-label-using-jquery-and-accessing-it-on-page-load-eve)

Comment: My comment on your other question still applies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961848/setting-value-of-an-asp-net-label-using-jquery-and-accessing-it-on-page-load-eve#comment22750275_15961848

Answer (score 0):

label is not input type so you can not get changed values through jquery on server side. You can use hidden field for this purpose.

Comment: I just tried hiddenfield with val using jquery, but hiddenfield1.value displays nothing.

Comment: .NET `PageLoad` event is fired way before the jQuery `window load`. Think about it?

Comment: the generated HTML source displays "Label" in <span> element that is why i guess the variable takes this value and saves it.. how can we fix that?

Comment: is there any way to Fix this?? i mean delay the Page Load function?

Comment: Yes thanks for the Support, i finally got the idea, now i used querystring to pass the values from last page to this one by jquery. thanks again.

Comment: Its always great pleasure to help .

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
       if($('#<%= Txt1.ClientID %>').val() != "Ronaldo"){
         var myNewName = "Ronaldo";
         $('#<%= Txt1.ClientID %>').val(myNewName);
         $('#<%= Label1.ClientID %>').text(myNewName);
         $('#<%= Btn1.ClientID %>').click();
       }
    });
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Txt1" runat="server" style="display:none"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Btn1" runat="server" style="display:none" Click="Btn1_Click"></asp:Label>
</form>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
      Label1.Text=Txt1.Text;

      string mynameCheck = Label1.Text;
      if (mynameCheck=="Ronaldo")
      {
        Response.Write("Yes Name is Fine");
      }
      else
      {
        Response.Write("Name's not Fine");
      }
    }
}

protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nope, Still Displays Name not Fine.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer: do you want the value on first time page load, or in a postback??

Comment: @designerNProgrammer : Then you should be informed that, after the severside PageLoad completes, the jquery script will fire in client-side. There is no way you can fire the jquery script before the first PageLoad of an asp.net webpage.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer : But you can get the desired value in PageLoad through this code, in any postback.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer : There is a fix I can think of, but it will delay the normal time the page should take to be rendered in the browser. I will update to my answer.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer : can you try the updated code once? Let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks for the effort man i finally used Querystrings for it. They worked. thanks again. cheers :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28098/discussion-between-avishek-and-designernprogrammer)

Answer (score 0):

Your server side code (c#) can not access the form data until your client side code (HTML/Javascript) posts it.

Why do you want to the name already at the `PageLoad` event?

You could add a `asp:Button` with an attached `onClick` event handler to read the value of your `asp:Label`.

Comment: Because i want the name from another page using jquery cookies and when the new details page is loaded, the details information can be displayed with ADO by using that value from Label. i hope you get the Idea. :0 please Help me Stefan, this is real Important.

Comment: Either use the QueryString to pass the additional data or try to read the cookie using c#.

Comment: Thanks for the Idea Buddy. the Whole stuff is passed using quertystring by javascript and the name of the item is retrieved on a label in New page using C#. Thanks the problem is solved Now.. thanks a lot. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Labels do not maintain viewstate. The server will not post that information back to the server. You can try explicitly enabling the ViewState on your Label, but if that doesn't work, you will have to store that value in a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

First Call `Page Load event` and after that call `JQuery Window.Load event`.

So if you want to set any content in Label then you can do using onClientClick of button.

For ex.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click me" OnClientClick="SetClientValues();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetClientValues() {
        var myNewName = "Ronaldo";        
        $('#<%= Label1.ClientID %>').text(myNewName);
    }
</script>
```

At server side button event you can get Label values that sets at client side.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string mynameCheck = Label1.Text;
        if (mynameCheck=="Ronaldo")
        {
            Response.Write("Yes Name is Fine");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Name's not Fine");

        }
}
```

It will print **Yes Name is Fine**

Comment: That's on Button CLick Right, i wanted that on Page Load.

Comment: It's not going to happen on page load. I'm sure that you can appreciate everyone's suggestions that what you're asking for is impossible.